# how to get end of file(EOF)

Tags: android, file

I have this code..
    

            `String you = buf.readLine(); 
            Log.d("STRING", ikaw);
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(you);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            int type = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            String text = st.nextToken();
            Log.d("File Reading stuff", "success = " + lat);
            Log.d("File Reading stuff", "success = " + lng);
            Log.d("File Reading stuff", "success = " + type);
            Log.d("File Reading stuff", "success = " + text);`

How am i suppose to test if it is already the end of file?
I don't know how many lines there are in my file and I need to print all of them. 
I know i should place my code inside a while loop, but I have no idea how to get the end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the code you have listed is inside a loop, and I assume buf is an instance of [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).  You just need to check for null after you call readLine().  It returns null when you've hit the end of the file.

Comment: indeed. i'd throw in that instead of doing a `for` loop, it's rather customary to do a `while` that includes the nullcheck: `String you; while ((you = buf.readLine()) != null) { ... }`